# Recommended way to execute code when CollectionView.SourceCollection changes

Tags: wpf, events, collectionview

I have an ObservableCollection of items that I want to present in two controls simultaneously: One for editing properties for the current selection and adding and deleting items, and one for displaying the entire collection with the current selection highlighted.

To this end I create a CollectionViewSource that binds to my items, and bind to that in my controls:

```
<UserControl>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="MyCollectionViewSource" Source="{Binding MyItems}">
        <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
            <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="MyProperty" />
        </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <my:PropertiesControl TheItems="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}}" >
    <my:DisplayControl TheItems="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyCollectionViewSource}}" >
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The problem is that in DisplayControl I want to arrange the items in a special way that can not be specified through XAML: The placement of an item depends not only on its own properties but also on that of the other items in the collection. Thus I need to execute some repositioning code whenever items are added to or deleted from the collection, or when the properties of one of the items in the collection changes.

I was wondering, what is the recommended way of going about this? Inspired by ItemsControl.ItemsSource I was thinking about making the TheItems properties be of type IEnumerable, but I have trouble figuring out how to proceed.

Any input will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

in the codebehind for your display control, wich i assume is a custom control of your own creation, you can get "TheItems" and reorder them to your hearts content... since you are using an ObservableCollection, you can "attach" to the CollectionChanged event and check for the condition (see the event args being passed in) that new items are added/removed and reorder at that time.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into that approach, and I ran into a couple of issues:

Comment: Thanks, I was looking into that approach, and I ran into a couple of issues. 1: If I connect to the CollectionChanged event on the View or the SourceCollection then the sender argument to the CollectionChanged event will be either the view or the collection. But I need to access the DisplayControl object to perform the repositioning! 2: CollectionChanged doesn't fire when the properties on the items are changed.

Answer (score 0):

Dont you already have sorting implemented using `MyProperty`? Why cant you use `Myproperty` that can hold some calculated order that uniquely sorts the items when they are added / deleted / edited.

I mean from the Model perspective you always **know** when an item is added and deleted (using `ObservableCollection.CollectionChanged` handler) or edited (using `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` handler of each item in your list). So when u handle these events, you will have to **update** your `MyProperty` that will hold value for each item so that the reordering would take place as per your expected logic.

Comment: Sorting isn't sufficient; the arrangement of items is in 2 dimensions and depends on several properties of the items. I ended up doing something like what you describe to get notification on changes to item properties, but I still have the problem of getting a reference to my control from the CollectionView/ObservableCollection that is passed to the event handler as sender. At the moment I use a static Dictionary that maps the CollectionView to the control. But this isn't a very robust solution. I would greatly appreciate sugestions on how to improve this.